# Find specific text and return cell changing the cell's color

Tags: excel, vba

I need a button that identifies the cell of the letter "ç" on the column D and change the color of the cell to red.
I've tried this code, but it's not working.

```
Sub LettersPT()
Dim Rng As Range
Dim cell As Range
Dim MSG, vazio As String

Set Rng = Range(Range("1"), Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
'Columns(2).Interior.ColorIndex = 0
For Each cell In Rng

    Set cells = cells.Find(What:="ç", LookIn:=xlFormulas, Lookat _
        :=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:= _
        False, SearchFormat:=False)

    If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Rng, cell.Value) > 1 Then
        MSG = MSG & cell.Address(RowAbsolute:=False, ColumnAbsolute:=False) & ", "
        cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 3


    End If
    If cells Is Nothing Then
        Else
        MsgBox ("Portuguese letters in " & cells.Address)
    End If

End Sub
```

The error is

> "Compile error: Invalid use of property."

Comment: `Range("1")` is not valid. Did you mean that to be `D1`?

Comment: "It's not working" - could you be more informative please?

Comment: Thank you, just realised I wasn't clear enought. The error is "Compile error: Invalid use of property."

Comment: 1) `Set Rng = Range(Range("1"), Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))` would be better as `Set Rng = Range("D" & Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)`  2)There is no need to iterate through every cell in that range if you are going to use `.Find()`. Just `Rng.Find(...` directly 3) There's a lot of strange nonsense inside your loop. I would remove the loop completely and just stick with `Rnd.Find()` to see if you get results you after before getting more fancy.

Comment: Which line? You're missing a Next.

Comment: `Set cells` is not possible `Cells` is already defined by Excel you cannot use it as variable and `Set` it. Don't use reserved names as variable names. • Also I recommend always to activate `Option Explicit`: In the VBA editor go to *Tools* › *Options* › *[Require Variable Declaration](https://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/option-explicit.html)*. • Note that if you `Dim MSG, vazio As String` only `vazio` is of type `String` but `MSG` is `Variant` you need to specify a type for **every** variable in VBA `Dim MSG As String, vazio As String`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to count how many cells that has letter ç and color matched records to visual.
Also assume that you only want to search through column D. Try the below

```
Dim Rng         As Range
Dim cell        As Range
Dim MSG         As String
Dim vazio       As String
Dim i           As Long


Set Rng = Range(Range("D1"), Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))

For Each cell In Rng

    If cell.Value Like "*ç*" Then
        cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 3
        MSG = MSG & vbNewLine & cell.Address
        i = i + 1
    End If


Next

If i = 0 Then
    MsgBox ("No Portuguese letters found")
Else
    MsgBox (i & " Record(s) Found" & vbNewLine & "Portuguese letters in " & MSG)

End If
```